# Website caching site

Tags: cache

Google and archive.org both cache/archive sites, however neither of them are fast enough and they don't cache everything.

Is there some site where you can input a url and it will go grab it and store it?

I find myself in need for proving what was on a site at a time. You can just save as the page, but that isn't very authoritative.

Comment: It's trivial to grab a copy of a site's content, so why does the cached copy need to be "authoritative"? (Keep in mind that any "grabber" service is going to have the same problems of authority that a locally-saved copy would)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Archive.org has a paid-for service called [Archive-It](http://www.archive-it.org/) that allows you to harvest your (or any) site as often as you like.

[Hanzo Archives](http://www.hanzoarchives.com/) offer a similar service, target at the corporate sector and legal compliance for data retention.

Data from both services should be usable in a court of law to prove what was on a site at a given point in time. Given Hanzo's focus on the corporate sector (the Internet Archive focuses more on the research community), they are probably a better choice for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option would be to use a browser screenshot website that hosts a screenshot for an extended period of time.

As far as I know, [BrowserShots.org](http://browsershots.org) is the only site that stores the screenshots at a publicly accessible location and often captures from the top to the bottom of the website, not just what're would appear without scrolling. You may need to pay to have them stored there for an extended period of time.

It won't be fast, but Yahoo and Blekko also cache websites.

Answer (score 0):

The [Pinboard](http://pinboard.in) bookmarking service offers an archive feature in their $25/ year paid account that caches every page you bookmark to keep a record of it should it disappear. More info about how it works in their [blog post here.](http://blog.pinboard.in/2010/11/bookmark_archives_that_don_t/) I've been using pinboard for about six months and have been very happy with the service.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTrack Website Copier - Offline Browser](http://www.httrack.com/) is a freeware windows app. It makes it easy to pull down a copy of your website for archiving.  You can set some pretty granular options to specify for example only specific filetypes, filesizes or site subdirectory depth.  The default options will pull down everything.

[image: HTTrack Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a screenshot service like [Browshot](http://browshot.com/) to take regular screenshots of your website. You could use a cron job and use [curl](http://browshot.com/api/command-line/curl) or [wget](http://browshot.com/api/command-line/wget).